# How does static block works across different classes in java?

Tags: java, jvm, initialization, classloader, static-block

```
class Details {
    static private int age;
    static {
        age=45;
        System.out.println("Static block.");
    }

    private String name;
    {
        name="Satyam";
        System.out.println("Initialiser block");
    }
    Details(){
        System.out.println("constructor.");
    }
    static void staticMethod(){
        System.out.println("static method.");
    }
    void nonStaticMethod(){
        System.out.println("non-static method");
    }

}




public class EncapsulationPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main method");
        Details.staticMethod();
        Details details=new Details();
        details.nonStaticMethod();

    }
}
```

I'm getting output in this way :

```
main method
Static block.
static method.
Initialiser block
constructor.
non-static method
```

But as far as the blogs I read and vedios I watched they told that static variables and static blocks are initialized before the obj creation i.e at the time of class loading? **I'm confused between class loading and initialization and I was expecting the output of above code as following:**

```
Static block.
main method
static method.
Initialiser block
constructor.
non-static method
```